# text to speech not working for all the text (in php form)

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, audio

I am making a voice dictionary. Here is the code . Its working fine except for problem that text to speech is working for some specific texts only. 
Eg if the string returned to the variable $y="hello world" then its being converted to audio
but if its "world hello" then there is no audio output.

plz help. thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Word meanings</title>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "abcd");
mysql_select_db("dictionary");
if(isset($_POST['Submit1']))
{

  $req=$_REQUEST['word'];
  $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dict WHERE word='$req'";
  $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
  {
     $x=$row["word"];
     $y=$row["meaning"];
     $z=$row["synonym"];
     echo "<b>Word</b>: " . $x ."<br/>" ;
     echo "<b>Meaning</b>: " . $y ."<br/>" ;
     echo "<b>Synonym</b>: " . $z ."<br/>" ;
  }
}
mysql_close();
?>

</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" action="lastry.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="word" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['word'])?$_POST['word']:''?>"x-webkit-speech/>
<Input Type ="Submit" Name ="Submit1" Value ="submit"> 
</form>
<?php  if($_POST)
{
?>

<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=<?php echo urlencode($y);?>&type="audio/mp3"     />
</audio>
<?php }?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* unless you want to be hacked. Don't do select * unless you want very slow performance. Use prepared statements instead of word='$req' unless you want to be hacked. Don't mix PHP and html, bugs will come and will be hard to understand (like now). What's the results if you dump your selected results? Are they perhaps empty? And please, don't do PHP execution in your head... It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem in API, which you use, go to 
http://tts-api.com/
and put "word hello", you'll get redirect to
http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=word%20hello
where you can see only 500.
So, you need contact API support.

Comment: yeah right. I have sent a mail , hope they look into the matter soon

Comment: It seems to support a small set of sentances.

Comment: You deserve a +1 @Alexey, here goes mine.